# Can we create ENUM on INTEGER column in PSQL?

Tags: database-design, enums, psql

I'm using PSQL and I'm trying to create a table with columns REQ_TYPE and RESP_STATUS. And I've decided to go with ENUM to avoid invalid entries in the table.

I've used this Query to create ENUM for REQ_TYPE successfully.

> CREATE TYPE RequestType AS ENUM('GET','POST','PUT','DELETE','PATCH');

But for RESP_STATUS, when I tried the below query,

> CREATE TYPE ResponseStatus AS ENUM(200,201,202,204,301,302,304,400,401,403,404,405,413,415,429,500);

I got the response

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "200"

I'm sure that

> CREATE TYPE ResponseStatus AS ENUM('200','201','202');

would solve my problem. But I just want to keep RESP_STATUS as INTEGER.

Can I create ENUM on INTEGER? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum is a set of arbitrary labels, equal only to themselves; they're not a constraint on values of a particular type. Think of the strings in the type definition as more like column names or programming language constants than actual values.

You might instead be looking for a domain (see [documentation for `CREATE DOMAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)), which would allow you to effectively "sub-type" integer with a list of allowed values:

```
CREATE DOMAIN http_status AS integer 
CHECK (
    VALUE IN 
    (200,201,202,204,301,302,304,400,401,403,404,405,413,415,429,500)
)
```

However, as suggested in [Mike Sherrill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589021/157957), it might be more appropriate to use a normal integer column with a foreign key constraint pointing to a list of known HTTP status codes, as this allows:

- Details about the HTTP status to be stored (e.g. `description`, `is_error`, `is_redirect`)
- New HTTP statuses to be added more easily (for instance, you're missing `410 GONE` and `417 Expectation Failed` from your example)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create an ENUM on a set of integers. From [reading the fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html)

> Enum types take a list of one or more quoted labels

I can't fathom why you would want an ENUM of integers. Use integers directly, either in a CHECK constraint, or with a foreign key reference to a table of valid integers.

For HTTP status codes, which seems to be your target, a foreign key reference to a table of HTTP status codes *and their meaning* makes a lot of sense.

Comment: In many languages, entries in an enum have both a label and a value; I suspect this is what the OP was expecting. For instance in C you could write `enum STATUS { OK=200, NOT_FOUND=404 }` etc. Alternatively, they are thinking of something closer to a "domain". I agree with your conclusion, however, that a foreign key is more appropriate in this instance.